# JQuery validate regular expression to get interest rate

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I want regular expression to get rate of interest. I am wanting to accept following things:

Ex:

```
 0
 0.4
 0.44
 4
44
 4.00
44.00
 4.2
 4.22
44.22
```

Min 0 and Max 99.99

It must have to accept numeric as well as decimal values but not more than 99.99. Also it should take decimal after first or second digit and after third digit it should display an error message.

I am trying this regular expression but its not perfectly working for me.

```
$.validator.addMethod('interest', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,4}/.test(value);
}, 'Please specify a valid data');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the above the decimal point is optional dot and you can add up to four numbers on top of the first two

Comment: @vogomatix: Yes which is wrong

Comment: this site will help you with regex: https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: @Ultimate, could I just confirm, do you only want 2 decimal places? or more, because it seems like you do but it's somewhat unclear.

Comment: @MikeH-R: I want only 2 decimal places

Comment: alright, well my regex will work fine, I also think @Cerbrus's answer should work fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex to match all of those numbers between 0 and 99.99 would be:

```
^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

so you're pretty close, but your regex matches 0 to 4 digits after the .

EDIT: forgot `^$`

Comment: `$.validator.addMethod('interest', function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?/.test(value);
    }, 'Please specify a valid data');` I've added this but its not properly validating

Answer (score 3):

Why mess with regexes if you can simply check for the value:

```
var input = parseFloat(value)
return !isNaN(input) && input >= 0 && input < 100;
```

If you want to make sure there are at most 2 decimal placed in the string, the check will be a little longer:

```
return !isNaN(input) &&
       input >= 0 &&
       input < 100 &&
       !(value.split('.')[1] && value.split('.')[1].length > 2);
```

Comment: Needs >= 0 not just > 0

Comment: @Ultimate: Sure, it'll validate `55.55`, since that's between `0` and `100`

Comment: @Cerbrus: There is one issue. its taking value like 5..6. Which is wrong. How can I validate that here?

Comment: Note the use of the standard isNaN function is not reqarded as a good idea. See [here for explanation and alternatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: @Ultimate: Then you might want to use the [stricter `parseFloat` function found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#A_stricter_parse_function)

Comment: This works but does not ensure that output is 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Well its taking any value there like 5kk5, 5//5 that is string, special characters etc... so that's why I need a regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you use regex you will end up having two problems. Try:

```
function validateStuff(input) {
    return ($.isNumeric(input) && input >= 0 && input <= 99.99);   
}


// Testing:
console.log(validateStuff(5));
console.log(validateStuff("Hello"));
console.log(validateStuff(100));
console.log(validateStuff(99.99));
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Cxc3/)**

Comment: This will validate negative numbers.

Comment: `console.log(validateStuff(98.999));` returns `true` OP stated that it should be 2 decimal places.

Comment: Ummm... no he didn't?

Comment: @martynas, you're right it wasn't clear, he has clarified that he does.

Comment: I want only 2 decimal places